# Como envío datos a una sola columna en un jtable

Tags: java, jtable

Estoy complicado con este código, lo mas probable es que sea simple pero no se como hacerlo.

Quiero introducir en una columna varios datos que tengo en distintos `jcombobox` y `jtexfield` (nombre, dirección, etc) pero para el programa que estoy haciendo necesito que todo vaya en una sola columna (columna "Descripción"), todo esto lo hago para ahorrar espacio en el `jtable`

De esta forma lo estoy intentando hacer:

```
public void mostrarDescripcion(){

        model3 = (DefaultTableModel)this.jTablemini.getModel();
        model3.addRow(new Object[filas]);
        for(int x=0;x<this.jTablemini.getColumnCount()-1;x++)
        {

            model3.setValueAt(promociones.getSelectedItem().toString(), filas, 0);
            model3.setValueAt(californiarolls.getSelectedItem().toString(), filas, 0);
           model3.setValueAt(californiaenvuelto.getSelectedItem().toString(), filas, 0);
            model3.setValueAt(specialrolls.getSelectedItem().toString(), filas, 0);
            model3.setValueAt(specialenvuelto.getSelectedItem().toString(), filas, 0);



        }
            filas++;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es concatenar todos los valores en un único String y luego ese ponerlo, algo así:

```
  String description = promociones.getSelectedItem().toString()+ 
                californiarolls.getSelectedItem().toString() + 
                californiaenvuelto.getSelectedItem().toString()+ 
                specialrolls.getSelectedItem().toString() +
                specialenvuelto.getSelectedItem().toString();

        model3.setValueAt(description, fila, 0);
```